# Stage changes in just the first line of hunk

Tags: magit

Consider the following situation:

```
$ printf $'line1-v1\nline2-v1\n' > test.txt
$ git init .
$ git add test.txt 
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit'
$ printf $'line1-v2\nline2-v2\n' > test.txt
```

Now, `magit-status` looks like this:

```
Head:     master Initial commit

Unstaged changes (1)
modified   test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-line1-v1
-line2-v1
+line1-v2
+line2-v2

Recent commits
285d881 master Initial commit
```

The task is to stage just the changes in the first line. But if you try doing it the obvious way (stage the removal of `line1-v1` and the addition of `line1-v2`), the lines end up in the wrong order in the index:

```
Head:     master Initial commit

Unstaged changes (1)
modified   test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-line2-v1
 line1-v2
+line2-v2

Staged changes (1)
modified   test.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-line1-v1
 line2-v1
+line1-v2

Recent commits
285d881 master Initial commit
```

The obvious work-around is to edit the source file and temporarily undo the changes to `line2`. But, is there a simpler way, which doesn't involve editing the source file?

If Magit had a way of editing the file's contents in the index, then that would be an option - one could then simply reorder the lines after staging, or just apply the edit there directly. But there is no way to do this, as far as I can tel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If Magit had a way of editing the file's contents in the index, then that would be an option

Magit's `ediff` commands allow this.  Use <kbd>E s</kbd> (`magit-ediff-stage`) and choose `test.txt` as the file to stage (alternatively, with point on the unstaged file in the status buffer, <kbd>e</kbd> (`magit-ediff-dwim`) will do the same).  This will pop up three buffers, with the middle ("B") `text.txt.~index~` buffer representing the index.  You can edit it as normal, or use ediff commands to apply whole hunks at a time.  Then quit the ediff session with <kbd>q</kbd>, and answer <kbd>y</kbd> to the `Update index with contents of text.txt.~index~` query.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible but I am considering a feature that would allow doing so: https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2938.

Comment: I guess this isn't happening.